# How to use LINQ with calculated properties in a single pass?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, properties

I'd like to make a LINQ query, extracting dynamic properties (calculated fields) of my entities in a single pass, without get the error "The specified type member 'EntityKey' is not supported in LINQ to Entities". 
Here is the only working way I found, but I am sure there are better and more elegant methods:

```
       var q = (from i in
                 (from x in context.Tickets
                    select new { x.OperatoreID, x.DataObiettivo })
                group i by new { i.OperatoreID } into g
                select new vmOperatoreDateObiettivo
                {
                    OperatoreID = g.Key.OperatoreID, 
                    NOperatore = "", // field value to be updated...
                    DataObiettivo = g.Max(d => d.DataObiettivo),
                    MinutiAllaScadenza = 0, // field to be updated...
                    Alert = "" // field value to be updated...
                }).ToList();

        // Here I update my fields with a second pass....

        foreach (vmOperatoreDateObiettivo e in q)
        {

            string nome = context.Operatori
                           .Where(t => t.OperatoreID == e.OperatoreID)
                           .First().CognomeNomePuntato.ToString();
            e.NOperatore = nome;
            int minscad = context.Tickets
                          .Where(t => t.OperatoreID == e.OperatoreID).AsEnumerable().Min(a => a.MinutiAllaScadenza);
            e.MinutiAllaScadenza = minscad;
            string sev = context.Tickets
                          .Where(t => t.OperatoreID == e.OperatoreID).AsEnumerable().Min(a => a.Alert);
            e.Alert = sev;             
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pheraps I used wrong terms...anyway I intend that the three fields are calculated...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a let clause to your query and define calculated field, like so:

```
var q = (from i in
        (from x in context.Tickets
            select new { x.OperatoreID, x.DataObiettivo })
         group i by new { i.OperatoreID } into g
         let nOperatore = context.Operatori
                           .Where(t => t.OperatoreID == e.OperatoreID)
                           .First().CognomeNomePuntato.ToString() &&
            minutialla = context.Tickets
                            .Where(t => t.OperatoreID == e.OperatoreID)
                            .AsEnumerable().Min(a => a.MinutiAllaScadenza) &&
            alert = context.Tickets
                      .Where(t => t.OperatoreID == e.OperatoreID)
                      .AsEnumerable().Min(a => a.Alert)
         select new vmOperatoreDateObiettivo
         {
             OperatoreID = g.Key.OperatoreID, 
             NOperatore = nOperatore,
             DataObiettivo = g.Max(d => d.DataObiettivo),
             MinutiAllaScadenza = minutialla,
             Alert = alert
         }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you @shuniar.
I am not sure let clause could really help me. 
Unfortunately I still have problems to get it work.
I corrected some sintax of above example: '&&' did not work, so I repeat let clause for each property; moreover, I had to use e.Key.OperatoreID, cause it's a subquery inside the 'group by'...now syntax is ok, but now I still have the same problems running the query "The specified type member 'EntityKey' is not supported in LINQ to Entities"...

Comment: I was wondering if should be possible to override dataset property with the calculated field? I mean to declare property as part of dbset (partial?) and then use calculated property in place of the stored one in dbset...after all, the exception says The specified type member 'EntityKey' is not supported in LINQ to Entities...if it were possible to 'cheat', making believe that you are using the entity in the schemes, you may be able to resolve the issue ... I apologize if the question may be silly, I'm just a beginner. THX!